# How to do vscode remote diff(diff over ssh) before sync?

Tags: visual-studio-code, diff, vscode-remote

I am using remote development option to connect linux machine from vscode and doing my development. As i am using two linux machines via remote development, Often i need to sync the files between them.

currently i am using rsync command to do the sync.

```
rsync -ravzh ./* root@linux2:/root/repo/dev
```

Also in vim there is an option to compare using vimdiff as below

```
vimdiff /path/to/file scp://root@<remotehost>//path/to/file
```

How can compare folders between two linux machine from vscode and sync?